# How to order execution of tests in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Please suggest best approach how to control order of test/spec execution in sbt?

Is there any option like [runOrder in maven-sirefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it cannot be done clearly for parallel execution, but it solvable for sequential:

```
parallelExecution in test := false

testGrouping <<= definedTests in Test map { tests =>
  tests.map { test =>
    import Tests._
    new Group(
      name = test.name,
      tests = Seq(test),
      runPolicy = InProcess)
  }.sortWith(_.name < _.name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, [not with parallel execution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/4SlL7pjDL3Y/cw_c0i9Chg0J). You can ask a test class to run its cases sequentially by [adding `sequential`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8030910/47978) to the beginning of its declaration.