# Run sbt tests in a particular order

Tags: scala, sbt

In my sbt project, I have two packages in it folder.

I want package.one tests to run first and then package.two. This is needed because tests in package.two are dependent on a Map created and populated by tests from the first package. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order execution of tests in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237420/how-to-order-execution-of-tests-in-sbt)

Comment: If your tests are not independent then they are not tests.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have following package structure:

```
p1/
  Test1.scala
p2/
  Test2.scala
```

Then you can run following commands:

```sh
sbt> testOnly -- -m "p1"

sbt> testOnly -- -m "p2"
```

This will execute tests from p1 first and then from p2