# How to run specifications sequentially

Tags: scala, specs2

I want to create few specifications that interoperate with database.

```
class DocumentSpec extends mutable.Specification with BeforeAfterExample {
  sequential

  def before() = {createDB()}
  def after() = {dropDB()}

  // examples
  // ...
}
```

Database is created and dropped before and after every example (which is executed sequentially). Everithing works as expected until there is only one spec that works with database. Because specifications are executed parallel, they interfere and fail.

I hope that I'm able to avoid this by instructing specs2 to run tests with side effects sequentially while keeping side effect free tests to run in parallel. Is it possible?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I suppose you are using SBT? If so, check the documentation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Parallel-Execution

The relevant SBT setting is `parallelExecution`. Add this to your project definition:

```
Test / parallelExecution := false
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using SBT. But it doesn't feel natural to specify settings of test suite inside build script. Besides, "parallelExecution in Test := false" ensures that all tests are run sequentially while I need to "to run tests with side effects sequentially while keeping side effect free tests to run in parallel". Maybe using separate db for every db test would be a solution.

Comment: Or simpler, put thoses tests in a distinct project and redefine `parallelExecution` for this project only.

Answer (score 42):

If you want to run single Specification in specs2 sequentially just add `sequential` method call at the beginning of your Specification. For example:

```
class MyTest extends Specification {
  // Set sequential execution
  sequential

  // This tests will be executed sequentially
  "my test" should {
    "add numbers" in {
      (1 + 1) should be equalTo 2
    }

    "multiply numbers" in {
      (2 * 2) should be equalTo 4
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** As @jsears correctly mentioned in the comments, this will make tests to run sequentially in a *single* spec! Other specs may still run in parallel.

Comment: You know, at my workplace, we're *still* not sure that this actually runs the tests in sequential order, or if it even prevents them running in parallel at all.

Comment: Weird... It worked for me and for many other people. If you can come up with an example when you tests are not executed sequentially with this method call, you should probably report a bug to spec2.

Comment: It does. See the response of Eric, the creator of Specs2 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026866/parallel-execution-of-tests

Comment: "sequential" runs the examples in a single spec in serial.  Other specs may still run in parallel, so if you have other specs with a shared fixture, you may see that happen in parallel.

Comment: @jsears That's correct. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 7):

Meanwhile there is a better solution (http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Parallel-Execution.html):

> sbt 0.12.0 introduces a general infrastructure for restricting task concurrency beyond the usual ordering declarations.

This configuration will run all tests sequential, also if they are in subprojects:

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global := Seq(
  Tags.limit(Tags.CPU, 2),
  Tags.limit(Tags.Network, 10),
  Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1),
  Tags.limitAll( 15 )
)
```

I haven't tested if this can be overridden by each sub-project, so the sub-project can run its tests in parallel.