# An exception or error caused a run to abort: Unable to start EmbeddedCassandra[name='cassandra-2', version='3.11.6']

Tags: cassandra, scalatest, cassandra-3.0, embedded-cassandra

I am using `embedded-cassandra` in my unit tests (Scalatest). When I try to run all the test cases as batch, I get error

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Unable to start EmbeddedCassandra[name='cassandra-2', version='3.11.6']
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 'WindowsCassandraNode[pid='-1', exitValue='0']' is not alive. Please see logs for more details
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file C:\Users\manuc\AppData\Local\Temp\apache-cassandra-3.11.6-5333812070060739596/logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory
...
ava.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    ERROR [main] 2020-09-17 06:27:11,872 CassandraDaemon.java:774 - Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
```

What I might be doing wrong? As the trace says `cassandra-2`, it seems that another instance of Cassandra is already running? Could it be that the tests are running simultaneously? What is the way to run tests serially in `Intellij/Scalatest`?

This answers mentions that Scalatest would run suits in parallel which might be causing the port conflict issue. Is there a way to avoid port conflict in `embedded-cassandra` or run suites serially? - [How to run tests in a class sequentially in ScalaTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463160/how-to-run-tests-in-a-class-sequentially-in-scalatest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use random ports to solve your issue:

```java
EmbeddedCassandraFactory cassandraFactory = new EmbeddedCassandraFactory();
cassandraFactory.setPort(0);
cassandraFactory.setSslPort(0); // if SSL client options enabled
cassandraFactory.setRpcPort(0);
cassandraFactory.setJmxLocalPort(0);
cassandraFactory.setStoragePort(0);
cassandraFactory.setSslStoragePort(0); // // if SSL server options enabled
```

Comment: Thanks. Does specifying 0 means random port?

Comment: Yes, Port with a value `0` will be replaced with a random one.

Comment: Thanks. I  added only `factory.setPort(0);` but am still getting bind error.`java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind` with `cassandra-2`

Comment: You should set jmxlocalport

Comment: Thanks. I also had to set `factory.setStoragePort(0);`. I could spawn up to 9 instances but then it stopped. Maybe I am hitting system limit. I'll update you. Thanks.